# Swift syntax discrepancy between parameters in initializer and functions

Tags: ios, swift, syntax

It seems to me that there is a discrepancy in Swift's syntax between calling an initializer and a function with at least one paremeter.

Let's consider these two examples:

```
class SimpleClass {

    var desc: String

    init(desc: String) {
        self.desc = desc
    }
}

let aClass = SimpleClass(desc: "description")
```

and

```
func simpleFunc(a: Int, b:Int) -> Int {
    return a + b;
}

let aVal = simpleFunc(5, b: 6)
```

It seems odd to me that the compiler forces you to omit the first label in a function call, otherwise you will get an error "Extraneous argument label 'a:' in call". Whereas if we want to omit the first label during initilization, you get the error "Missing argument label 'desc:' in call".

The language guide says:

> When calling a function with more than one parameter, any argument after the first is labeled according to its corresponding parameter name.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

> The arguments to the initializer are passed like a function call when
>   you create an instance of the class.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html

I'm new to Swift so I hope I didn't miss something, but this seems like a syntax discrepancy, because initializers/ constructors are just kind of functions and forcing to omit the first label in a function call seems inconsistent to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Swift focuses on readability; function calls to be able to be read like a sentence. See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html), specifically the section on "Local and External Parameter Names for Methods". Your function, to comply with this style, should be more like:

```
func add(a: Int, to b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

let c = add(1, to: 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explenation, still seems really unusual to me.

Comment: Swift inherited Objective C style where parameter name is usually a part of function name: [self addA:1 toB: 2]   Swift: addA(1, toB: 2)

Comment: Init is a special case. It's a keyword, you can't create initA() or initB(), it's always init(), so first parameter name is required by default.